# Rebuild the xDB index in Solr - error mongo

Tags: xdb, solr, indexing

I have problem with rebuilding xDB index in solr.
I changed `IndexPIISensitiveData` to true in job SerachIndexer and
after executing the command `\XConnectSearchIndexer.exe -rr` there is no sensitive data from facet in the indexes. They are added only for "new" data in xDb (postponed after changing the flag)

Additionally, I noticed (I don't know if it is related) an error in the logs:

> [Error] Command find failed: errmsg: "Sort operation used
> more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify
> a smaller limit.".
> Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Data.MongoDb.Exceptions.MongoDbProviderException:
> Command find failed: errmsg: "Sort operation used more than the
> maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller
> limit.". ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command find
> failed: errmsg: "Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432
> bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.".

But the rebild command was theoretically correct (I did it on an empty xdb_rebuild index).
In the hints for the problem with mongo there are ideas for creating an index, but I don't know what to put it on. Increasing the RAM memory also does not make sense - this base is very large. Or maybe this has nothing to do with the problem? The goal is to re-index the xdb database in order to display a person with sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/configuring-the-xconnect-search-indexer.html

You need to control the parameters: ParallelizationDegree and BatchSize.

Comment: Hi @Jan, what did you set the values to for the parameters mentioned above?

Comment: The parameters will vary depending on your environment. This article can be helpful: https://sitecoreart.martinrayenglish.com/2019/09/sitecore-xdb-optimizing-your-xdb-index.html

Comment: Hi @Jan, thanks for the link. I've tried many different indexer configurations on a bug we had recently. Turned out that the root cause was different than what you had encountered, the symptoms however were similar.